# Google Fit API - How you can read DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CADENCE from history client

Tags: android, google-fit

I'm trying to get differents types of data from the History Client of Google fit API.
By now I can read the history of DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA & DataType.TYPE_DISTANCE_DELTA,

but I can't have any data about the DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CADENCE, the dataSet of this type never contains any dataPoints.

Can anyone help me on this one?

Here's how I do:

Request:

```
Fitness.getHistoryClient(context, account)
            .readData(DataReadRequest.Builder()
                        .read(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CADENCE)
                        .read(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
                        .read(DataType.TYPE_DISTANCE_DELTA)
                        .setTimeRange(
                            configuration.startTime.timeInMillis,
                            configuration.endTime.timeInMillis,
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                        )
                        .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.HOURS)
                        .enableServerQueries()
                        .build()
                )
                .addOnSuccessListener { response ->
                    liveDataUpdates.value = PedometerSensorData.fromBuckets(response.buckets)
                }
```

Parsing Data:

```
fun fromBuckets(buckets: List<Bucket>): List<PedometerSensorData> {

        ...

        buckets.forEach { bucket ->
            bucket.dataSets.forEach { dataSet ->
                if(dataSet.dataType == DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CADENCE) {
                    Log.d("TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CADENCE", "STEP COUNT CADENCE IS EMPTY ${dataSet.isEmpty}")
                }

                ...

            }
    }
```

Comment: I think the cadence calculation was disabled because it wasn't actually being used. So, it's empty because there's no data there.

Answer (score 0):

The only calculation that Fit ever did to compute cadence was to take points of type `DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA` and divide the value by the duration of the point.

So, if you want cadence data, I'd suggest doing that over an appropriate interval.